# NetworkManager fails with ,,No secrets were provided'' on a mbpro 15,2

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager, macintosh, iwd

after some initial problems I was able to successfully install Arch on my macbook pro (15,2 - 2019 model). Mainly used the awesome t2linux wiki - so it's aunali1's modified kernel. Everything seems to work fine, the touchbar is so-so, audio sometimes panics the kernel etc but no deal breakers so far. So thanks for the awesome work to all the people who made this even possible!

Wifi model is broadcomm 4364 maui x3. I *know* the wifi works; it sometimes was able to connect, seemed like once out of 10 tries but now it fails everytime (not that there's any use for wifi that fails nine out of ten times..). FWIW it also works if I disable the wpa security on the AP. Tried deleting/recreating kwallet, disabling kwallet altogether (following some advice found elsewhere), tried through iwd directly, no avail - says 'Operation failed'. The same thing appears in journalctl (see below). Wpa_supplicant is installed, tried disabling/stopping/etc (following advice from elsewhere).

Of course I'm no genius about these things, so maybe I'm doing something very silly, though I've been able to use wifi on all our linux devices (mostly arch, one raspberry, one late 2008 macbook, all working).

It's my home AP, some older mikrotik model; the setup has been working trouble free for a long long time.

One more note; if I try to delete the connection from KDE config panel, it always fails with ,,error checking authentication connection was deleted'' .. but it disappears nonetheless. I don't recall ever seeing this problem, but I rarely delete a connection so.. uh.

From jounralctl:

```
Jul 12 09:08:48 tuxbookpro NetworkManager[336]: <info>  [1626073728.2010] device (wlan0): Activation: starting connection 'les20x' (bd9309e3-98dd-4d29-b380-b250dc1917d2)
Jul 12 09:08:48 tuxbookpro NetworkManager[336]: <info>  [1626073728.2011] audit: op="connection-add-activate" uuid="bd9309e3-98dd-4d29-b380-b250dc1917d2" name="les20x" pid=671 uid=1000 result="success"
Jul 12 09:08:48 tuxbookpro NetworkManager[336]: <info>  [1626073728.2014] device (wlan0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 12 09:08:48 tuxbookpro NetworkManager[336]: <info>  [1626073728.2017] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 12 09:08:48 tuxbookpro NetworkManager[336]: <info>  [1626073728.2041] device (wlan0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 12 09:08:48 tuxbookpro NetworkManager[336]: <info>  [1626073728.2139] device (wlan0): state change: need-auth -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 12 09:08:48 tuxbookpro NetworkManager[336]: <info>  [1626073728.2350] device (wlan0): new IWD device state is connecting
Jul 12 09:08:53 tuxbookpro NetworkManager[336]: <error> [1626073733.0081] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) Network.Connect failed: GDBus.Error:net.connman.iwd.Failed: Operation failed
Jul 12 09:08:53 tuxbookpro NetworkManager[336]: <info>  [1626073733.0085] device (wlan0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 12 09:08:53 tuxbookpro NetworkManager[336]: <warn>  [1626073733.0093] device (wlan0): Activation: failed for connection 'les20x'
Jul 12 09:08:53 tuxbookpro NetworkManager[336]: <info>  [1626073733.0096] device (wlan0): new IWD device state is disconnected
Jul 12 09:08:53 tuxbookpro NetworkManager[336]: <info>  [1626073733.0102] device (wlan0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

Thanks for any clues.

****************************************** output after Jeff Isaacs' clues

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'les20x'
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 status_code=16
wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'les20x'
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
wlan0: Associated with 00:0c:42:fb:c6:61
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:0c:42:fb:c6:61 completed [id=0 id_str=]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
```

so probably a problem with NetworkManager (thanks Jeff!) .. thanks for any further clues..

---

further logs

```
local# find /etc/systemd -name \*.service -type l -a -xtype f -printf %f\\n                                                                                             /home/pklement
getty@tty1.service
display-manager.service
NetworkManager-wait-online.service
dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service
iwd.service
NetworkManager.service
dhcpcd.service
xdg-user-dirs-update.service
pipewire-media-session.service
```

journalctl -b is huge, posted to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/TchRuNS2). The errors on lines 411-413 which I've now fixed seemed to solve the problem.. blows my mind. Thanks for your help sir!

---

FWIW, after system upgrade the error was back. Even the manual wpa_supplicant way was not working; errcode 16, operation failed, beh. Had to manually downgrade networkmanager, libnm and iwd to their previous versions and now it works again. Something's fishy in this setup of mine.

```
[ALPM] downgraded networkmanager (1.32.4-1 -> 1.32.2-1)
[ALPM] downgraded iwd (1.15-1 -> 1.13-1)
[ALPM] downgraded libnm (1.32.4-1 -> 1.32.2-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if you can connect to your AP without using NetworkManager.

First stop NetworkManager and wpa_supplicant.

```
# systemctl stop NetworkManager
# systemctl stop wpa_supplicant
```

Then create a conf file for wpa_supplicant.

```
# /etc/wpa_supplicant/my_network.conf

ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
ap_scan=1

network={
    ssid="MYSSID"     #include the quotes
    psk="MYPASSWORD"  #include the quotes
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Make sure that your interface is up.

```
# ip link set wlan0 up
```

Next start wpa_supplicant using the conf file you created.

```
# wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/my_network.conf
```

If that runs with no errors, but you do not have an IP address, run

```
# dhcpcd wlan0
```

This is assuming you use DHCP, so if you are able to pull an address then your problem is a NetworkManager problem. If you don't pull an address, post the output from the wpa_supplicant terminal.

Comment: Yes, this works successfully  (I didn't  need to kick dhcpd, worked okay). I'll add the output to the original post. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: It seems like there may be multiple services trying to control your wireless card. Post the output of  `find /etc/systemd -name \*.service -type l -a -xtype f -printf %f\\n` and `journalctl -b`

Comment: Hi sir, so the errors I've found in journalctl (see original post) seems to have solved this issue. Don't get how but they did :D Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a similar problem when trying to connect to a EAP-TLS WiFi (Kubuntu). Posting here in case someone else ends up here when searching for "Network Manager no secrets were provided"

There is a setting that is not no exposed to NM UI. It removes the required password flag for the private key.

Running the following command in the terminal solved the issue:

```
# nmcli con modify [WIFI_SSID] 802-1x.private-key-password-flags 4
# nmcli con show [WIFI_SSID] | grep "802-1x.private-key-password-flags
802-1x.private-key-password-flags:      4 (not required)
```

- Adding a passphrase to the key doesn't solve the issue.

Hint came from here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6334111

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/416991)